# Ruby_on_Rails Testing The Database Using Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Actually i am newbie to rails testing

I want to know what are all the step covered in the rails testing.?

Could anyone help me knowing the steps involve in **Professional Testing**

Comment: Have you read through the guide on Ruby on Rails Testing? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: you'll have to get more specific with your question then. What parts are you having trouble with?

Comment: I didn't get clear idea about **Unit_Testing**

Answer (score 1):

Check out the rails guide Gavin linked you. Can also check out this book: http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book. It covers how to use rspec, and covers testing various parts of the application.

I also rather enjoyed Rails 3 in action, which teaches the basics and various topics of rails, while doing inside-out testing throughout the entire book. Rails 4 in action is a work in progress edition as well.

As for my answer:

Generally testing first before you write code makes the process better & easier. Writing tests after the fact isn't as nice, even though it does give you the coverage. When it's part of your regular workflow to add features, it's quite nice. If you have a new feature that you want to add, such as user sign up that sends a confirmation email. You can write the integration test first. It describes the user as going through the sign up form, filling it properly, and then checking if an email was sent.

From there you can test internals of the user model, making sure methods you build for this to work function as expected. Then when you have your tests green, add another scenario to the integration tests where the login was invalid.

Comment: :)-  can you post some-other link for free cost

Comment: I would if i knew of any. The resources ive used for testing have been the ones ive linked above, where i've either bought the book myself, or borrowed it from someone. Sorry.

Comment: I can't believe nobody linked to this yet http://railscasts.com/episodes/275-how-i-test